# Wiremock - use random value from response body into postServeActions

Tags: jmeter, wiremock

this is __admin/mappings:
I have this response:
"response": {
"status":200,
"headers":{"Content-Type" : "application/json"},
"body": {"transactionID": "{{randomValue length=12 type='NUMERIC'}}","statusCode": "S01"}
}

I want to use the same randomized number  in postServeActions. how do I pass it?

```
"postServeActions" : 
 [{
    "name" : "webhook",
"parameters" : {
"method" : "POST",
"url" : "http://127.0.0.1:8081/sts/ADD?FILENAME=transactions.txt&LINE=<transactionID>&ADD_MODE=FIRST&UNIQUE=TRUE"
    }
}]
```

(   not tried                 )

Answer (score 0):

If your question is related to Wiremock, as per [Response Templating - Random Values](https://docs.wiremock.io/response-templating/random-values/) you should be able to use something like:

```
{{randomValue length=10 type='NUMERIC'}}
```

If you want to do the same in JMeter you can go for [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random)

```
${__Random(1000000000,9999999999,)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)